# Why does this RegExp cause the browser to crash?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was working on a RegExp and found out that if the string contains dash `aa-bb.js` and the query string part `m=123`, it will cause the browser to crash, apart from not being the best Regular Expression for this purpose, I'd like to know why does it work for `https://example.org/aa.js` and not for `https://example.org/js/aa-bb.js?m=123`

```
var re = /src=[\'|\"]([ -0-9a-zA-Z:]*[ 0-9a-zA-Z;]*)*[\'|\"]/g;
var result = re.exec("<script src='https://example.org/js/aa-bb.js?m=123'></script>");
console.log(result)
```

Comment: regex crash .. backtracking issues? look at [fixing-catastrophic-backtracking-in-regular-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463148/fixing-catastrophic-backtracking-in-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1):

Besides your regex has other problems,
your error is this (which probably caused the crash):

```
Error: Regex Construction .. 

Invalid range end in character class

     src= [\'|\"] 
     (                             # (1 start)
          [ -0-<<<HERE>>>9a-zA-Z:]* 
          [ 0-9a-zA-Z;]* 
     )*                            # (1 end)
     [\'|\"]
```

In the class, the range `<space> to 0`, then a range operator without the starting character.

---

Other problems:

This character class `[\'|\"]` has an alternation literal in it.
Do you intend that?

Also, you have optionally-quantified optional-quantifiers without specifying
something *non-optional*.
What makes this really bad is when you have classes which content overlap.
That is a recipe for backtracking overflow.

Example `([abcD]*[abc]*)*`

---

Overall, the regex you probably need is this `src=(['"])(?:(?!\1)[\S\s])*\1`