# Find blocks of lines starting with a certain character

Tags: python, regex

Text:

```
Abcd
Aefg
bhij
Aklm
bnop
Aqrs
```

(Note, there is no newline after the last line)

Python code:

```
print(re.findall('(^A.*?$)+',Text,re.MULTILINE))
```

This returns

```
['Abcd','Aefg','Aklm','Aqrs']
```

However, I would like adjacent lines to be returned as one set:

```
['Abcd\nAefg','Aklm','Aqrs']
```

How should I solve this with Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
((?:^A.*[\n\r]?)+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/SpmGPW/1/).
This is:

```
(
    (?:^A.*[\n\r]?)+ # original pattern 
                     # with newline characters, optionally
                     # repeat this as often as possible
)
```

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

data = """
Abcd
Aefg
bhij
Aklm
bnop
Aqrs"""

matches = [match.group(1).strip() 
           for match in re.finditer(r'((?:^A.*[\n\r]?)+)', data, re.M)]
print(matches)
```

Which yields

```
['Abcd\nAefg', 'Aklm', 'Aqrs']
```

It may lead to catastrophic backtracking eventually because of the nested quantifiers.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help! So my mistake was using `$` where I should have used `\n`, and I should have enclosed the whole pattern in a capturing group.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'^A.*(?:\nA.*)*', text, re.M)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kESAea/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `A` - an `A` letter
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\nA.*)*` - zero or more reptitions of

  - `\nA` - a newline and `A`
  - `.*` - the rest of the line.

Comment: That is a very smart alternative solution, I really like it! A very minor issue with it is having to repeat the line identifier (`A.*`), but for the rest a good idea.

Comment: @Peter It is following the best practices. If you ever have to add right-hand context to Jan's regex, you will get catastrophic backtracking (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463148/fixing-catastrophic-backtracking-in-regular-expression)) sooner or later.  There is absolutely no problem with repeating `A`. It makes the pattern match in such a way that the subsequent patterns cannot match the same text, which makes it fail safe. Also, you may compare the amount of steps with [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/kESAea/1) and [the alternative one](https://regex101.com/r/SpmGPW/1/).

Comment: @Peter If you ever need to repeat the same pattern in a Python regex, just use variables: `A = 'my\s+amazing\s+pattern\s+part'` and then `re.findall(rf'^{A}.*(?:\n{A}.*)*', text)`